# Как передать содержимое компонента TStringGrig от сервера к клиенту?

Tags: delphi

Как передать содержимое компонента TStringGrig от сервера к клиенту, используя компоненты TServerSocket И TClientSocket? Такая задача. Насколько я понимаю, делается методом SaveToStream. Кто сталкивался или знает, как сделать, можете подсказать, как примерно код должен выглядеть для сервера и клиента?

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй сохранять данные из грида в файл, а потом используй [данную информацию](http://sources.ru/magazine/1204/tsocket.html)